# Storing json objects in Google Analytics custom dimensions

Tags: google-analytics

I'm just wondering if there is a limit to the size of the value you can store in a Google Analytics custom dimension.

I'm thinking about adding lots of meta data and keys as a json string in a single custom dimension. This meta data is primarily used to join to other third party datasets and i'll be parsing out the keys and values in Big Query.

Just wondering if any hard limit to the size of string value a custom dimension can hold. Couldn't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cd_), the max length is 150 bytes (which [usually means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300929/how-many-characters-can-you-store-with-1-byte) 150 characters) for ASCII characters. If the value contains multibyte characters (like Russian characters or German Umlauts) it would be less than 150 characters.

See Maximum Length in [Measurement Protocol Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference#maxlength):

> All text values in the Measurement Protocol have specific maximum
>   lengths in bytes. for example the document referrer field, dr has a
>   maximum length of 2048 Bytes. If any of the values are greater than
>   the maximum lengths, they will automatically be truncated. If a
>   multi-byte character exceeds the maximum length, the entire character
>   will be truncated.

Comment: Thanks. There goes my json idea I think :(